# Failed cross domain xml Get Request

Tags: javascript, cors

Im trying to help a friend out with a program but my coding experience is somewhat dated (10 years give or take). Where trying to pull data from a database via their API. Im making this request via a XMLhttpRequest but im having issues even getting to the Server.

The error that occurs:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/jasper/api.shiftbase.com/api/rosters?min_date=2020-07-13&max_date=2020-12-31&department_id=24477
```

Its trying to search for the url on my own domain. But I need it to search cross domain.

The entire function:

```js
function getRequest(){
    var _request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var key = myKeyHere;
    var url = "api.shiftbase.com/api/rosters?min_date=2020-07-13&max_date=2020-12-31&department_id=24477";
    _request.onreadystatechange = function(event){
    console.log(_request.readyState + " + " + _request.status);
        if (_request.readyState == 4){
            if ((_request.status >= 200 && _request.status < 300) || _request.status == 304){
                alert(_request.responseText);
            } else {
                    alert('Request was unsucceful: ' + _request.status);
            }
        }
    };
    _request.open("get", url, true);
    _request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/JSON", false);
    _request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/JSON", false);
    _request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", key, false);
    _request.send(null);
};
```

I've also read a lot about CORS and how this affects these kinds of requests cross domain, but i don't quite understand how it works and how i can work arround it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your URL needs a `https://` prefix

Comment: Tried that aswell earlier (should have said in my initial post tbh), but then i get a ERR_HTTP_PROTOCOL_ERROR. Any idea what that is then?

Comment: That is probably because you have invalid characters in your headers. `application/JSON` should be `application/json`. And from what i could find from a [quick search](https://differentlab.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/format) is that your API KEY should be in the following format `API [your key]`

Comment: Tnx, seems the JSON in cappital was the issue /facepalm. Concerning the key. I was using that setup but didn't want to put my key on the internet just in case ^^. Greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to prefix your URL with `https://`. This way you make a request to the external server instead of localhost. The second thing is that in your headers the `application/JSON` should be `application/json`.

Also dont forget that your key needs to be [prefixed](https://differentlab.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/format) with "API". Example `API [some_random_key]`

I've tested the following code and it worked. You just have to add your own API KEY.

```js
function getRequest(){
    var _request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var key = "API [replace_this_with_your_key]"; // Example: "API a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9"
    var url = "https://api.shiftbase.com/api/rosters?min_date=2020-07-13&max_date=2020-12-31&department_id=24477";
    _request.onreadystatechange = function(event){
    console.log(_request.readyState + " + " + _request.status);
        if (_request.readyState == 4){
            if ((_request.status >= 200 && _request.status < 300) || _request.status == 304){
                alert(_request.responseText);
            } else {
                    alert('Request was unsucceful: ' + _request.status);
            }
        }
    };
    _request.open("get", url, true);
    _request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json", false);
    _request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json", false);
    _request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", key, false);
    _request.send(null);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `//` at the start of the line in `url` variable declaration (line 4), if you want to make a request to the external server.

Your request was made to the local webserver `http://localhost/jasper/...` and you've received a 404 (not found) error.

Comment: Tried you suggestion and it seems to move in the right direction. It now throws the following error: 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.shiftbase.com/api/rosters?min_date=2020-07-13&max_date=2020-12-31&department_id=24477' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

So i seem to run into the CORS issue i described earlier. any ideas?